# Applying a CSS style to an element using multiple selectors fails

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to find out what I am doing wrong. I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="dialog-container">
    <div id="dialog-box" title="" >
        <div id="dialog-icon" >
            &nbsp;
        </div>
        <p>
        <span id="dialog-message"></span>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have some CSS which floats to the left. If I enter the following it works

```
#dialog-box #dialog-icon
{
    float: left; 
    height: 32px; 
    width: 32px;   
}
```

but if I enter 1 more rule i.e insert `#dialog-container` before the `#dialog-box` then it's not applied like this:

```
#dialog-container #dialog-box #dialog-icon
{
    float: left; 
    height: 32px; 
    width: 32px;   
}
```

but I thought this means apply to dialog-icon that's inside a dialog-box and that is inside a dialog-container?

Am I missing something?

Comment: A closing </div> for dialog-box maybe?

Comment: That's a single selector that makes use of descendant combinators (the spaces between the IDs).

Comment: Re edit, is that new HTML code the one you meant to paste at the top? If so maybe you should replace that code block instead so your question is clearer.

Comment: ok doing it now.. its not new html.. i pasted it wrong.. i will update the question

Comment: Hmmm, that selector should work just fine... could you look in your stylesheet and see if there's anything else that might be overriding that rule?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You HTML is not correctly formed or structured for your needs. You are missing a closing DIV tag on the second DIV. This is maybe what you need:

```
<div id="dialog-container">
    <div id="dialog-box" title="" >
        <div id="dialog-icon" >
            &nbsp;
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The way you had it, the third div was not treated as a child (or 'inside') the second.

**EDIT Following Update**

I've tested this in JSFiddle (adding a colour for red and some text to highlight). It seems to be working ok:

http://jsfiddle.net/WW3v2/

Do you have any more info?

Comment: Yes i think i had a problem with cache ... Sorry to trouble everyone... It was very strange as i also thought it should be working..

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have three opening `<div>` tags but only two closing ones.

Secondly, you don't need to declare `#id1 #id2` as `#id2` is an **identifier** and is only allowed to identify **one** element. It is sufficient to declare a rule for `#id2`.

Comment: Very true :-)  but i would like to know why its not working for when i need to use it with class names for example

Answer (score 0):

This

```
#dialog-container #dialog-box #dialog-icon
```

would match the following structure:

```
<div id="dialog-container">
    <div id="dialog-box">
        <div id="dialog-icon"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

but since your `dialog-icon` is not inside of `dialog-box` (at least not properly), this does not work.